# Repeating a certain line several times based on the length of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to repeat the line `A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]` several times based on the length of `B`. For instance, `len(B)=4` and `A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]` has been repeated 4 times. Is there a way to repeat `A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]` without writing it explicitly and get the same current output?

```
A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
B=[1,3,6,7]          

A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
print(A)
```

The current output is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for j in range(len(B)):
A = A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
```

Then just print normally after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
B=[1,3,6,7]          

for i in range(len(B)+1):
  A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
  print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
B=[1,3,6,7]          
x = 0
while x < len(B):
    A=A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
    x = x + 1

print(A)
```

While condition is not met, the loop will continue.

In this case, x being less than the length of B - which is to say how many items are in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a `for` loop over B (ignoring the actual values in B since they don't matter):

```
>>> A=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> B=[1,3,6,7]
>>> for _ in B:
...     A = A[:1] + [i + 1 for i in A]
...
>>> print(A)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```